# React-Redux: Receive and send form data (server)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, devextreme

I ask for help how to make devextreme form on redux.
No plugins: redux-form, formik and other. It seemed to me that they would be unnecessary, because Devextreme has many built-in features. Maybe I'm wrong.

I read this article, but maybe there is something simpler
https://medium.com/@pnpsegonne/tutorial-creating-a-form-with-react-redux-c1b3025cf26b

I need an example of how to get data from the server into the form fields. And how to change them and transfer them to the server by click on "Save" button. Of course, for example, the server can be replaced with a timeout function or something.
https://codesandbox.io/s/overview-devextreme-forms-and-multi-purpose-t86mw

```
import React from "react";

import { employee, positions, states } from "./data.js";

import Form, {
  SimpleItem,
  GroupItem,
  ButtonItem,
  Label
} from "devextreme-react/form";
import "devextreme-react/text-area";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.birthDateOptions = { width: "100%" };
    this.positionOptions = {
      items: positions,
      value: ""
    };
    this.stateOptions = {
      items: states
    };
    this.phoneOptions = { mask: "+1 (000) 000-0000" };
    this.notesOptions = { height: 140 };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Form formData={employee}>
        <GroupItem cssClass="first-group" colCount={4}>
          <SimpleItem render={avatarRender} />
          <GroupItem colSpan={3}>
            <SimpleItem dataField="FirstName" />
            <SimpleItem dataField="LastName" />
            <SimpleItem
              dataField="BirthDate"
              editorType="dxDateBox"
              editorOptions={this.birthDateOptions}
            />
          </GroupItem>
        </GroupItem>
        <GroupItem cssClass="second-group" colCount={2}>
          <GroupItem>
            <SimpleItem dataField="Address" />
            <SimpleItem dataField="City" />
            <SimpleItem
              dataField="Position"
              editorType="dxSelectBox"
              editorOptions={this.positionOptions}
            />
          </GroupItem>
          <GroupItem>
            <SimpleItem
              dataField="State"
              editorType="dxSelectBox"
              editorOptions={this.stateOptions}
            />
            <SimpleItem dataField="ZipCode" />
            <SimpleItem dataField="Mobile" editorOptions={this.phoneOptions}>
              <Label text="Phone" />
            </SimpleItem>
          </GroupItem>
          <SimpleItem
            colSpan={2}
            dataField="Notes"
            editorType="dxTextArea"
            editorOptions={this.notesOptions}
          />
        </GroupItem>
        <ButtonItem
          horizontalAlignment="left"
          buttonOptions={{
            text: "Save",
            type: "success",
            useSubmitBehavior: true
          }}
        />
      </Form>
    );
  }
}

function avatarRender() {
  return <div className="form-avatar" />;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be a marked assignment for developers on Stackoverflow? 
"I would like a detailed answer, this will help many developers" ?

Comment: Not for developers on Stackoverflow. I removed this part of the text to make the question clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need an example of how to get data from the server into the form fields. And how to change them and transfer them to the server by click on "Save" button. Of course, for example, the server can be replaced with a timeout function or something.

If this is the only thing that matters you then "you might not need redux". You can just call the API in your `componentDidMount` and `setState` with the desired data returned from the API.

> but maybe there is something simpler

Maybe not. Don't worry it will get easier with time.

For now, I have implemented API integration using redux and redux-saga [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/overview-devextreme-forms-and-multi-purpose-nwcjj).
Hope this is all you need.